# sublime text 2 phpcs plugin python error

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 with some plugins. I can't seem to work with the Phpcs plugin, because after saving the file, it gives me an ugly error:

```
Writing file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myProject/application/libraries/Authentication.php with encoding UTF-8
Exception in thread Thread-15:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "./phpcs.py", line 398, in run
File "./phpcs.py", line 128, in get_errors
File "./phpcs.py", line 194, in execute
File "./phpcs.py", line 197, in parse_report
File "./phpcs.py", line 149, in shell_out
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have also tried to look into the respective files, but I don't know python at all so  I don;t know what to do :-/

Could You please help ?

Comment: Do you have php in you path? Also on what OS are you running?

Comment: I guess I do, my codeigniter project is running for some months on my Xampp for mac os x 10.8.4

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using SublimeLinter plugin that provides the showing-potential-errors feature that I wanted from the phpcs plugin.

The plugin is located in [THIS GITHUB REPO](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter).

Hope this helps anybody who is having a problem using the phpcs library.

@daniel: Thanks for help